# Bash Programming infinite loop

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to bash and I am trying to learn it from online tutors. 
When I tried the below code on my computer(windows) with an xserver I am getting

```
1) Hello
2) Quit
#?
bad option
#?
```

and this continue infinitely, which I am not supposed to get. I used `./programname.txt`
to run the file
and my code is

```
#!/bin/bash
OPTIONS="Hello Quit"
select opt in $OPTIONS; do
   if [ "$opt" = "Quit" ]; then
       echo done
       exit
   elif [ "$opt" = "Hello" ]; then
       echo Hello World
   else
       clear
       echo bad option
   fi
done
```

someone please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should (un)format your question

Comment: What do you type exactly when you get this bad option?

Comment: @RaFD I didnt type anything since its by an echo result

Comment: What are you entering at the `select` prompt? `Hello`/`Quit` or `1`/`2`? It's a common mistake to enter the text in options, namely `Hello` or `Quit` in your example. You should enter `1` or `2`.

Comment: @RaFD  thanks a lot, I understood it only now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `man` page of `select` command clearly states where  you when wrong

*`select name [ in word ] ; do list ; done`*

*The list of words following in is expanded, generating a list of
              items.  The set of expanded words is  printed  on  the  standard
              error,  each  preceded  by a number.  If the in word is omitted,
              the positional parameters are printed  (see  PARAMETERS  below).
              The  PS3 prompt is then displayed and a line read from the stan-
              dard input.  If the line consists of a number  corresponding  to
              one  of  the  displayed  words, then the value of name is set to
              that word.  If the line is empty, the words and prompt are  dis-
              played again.  If EOF is read, the command completes.  Any other
              value read causes name to be set to  null.*

`select opt in $OPTIONS; do`

Here `OPTIONS` represent the `word` in the syntax. Now When the `OPTIONS` is expanded, the list `{Hello, Quit}` is obatained which is printed as output, presceded by a number, as in the earlier part of the output.

```
1) Hello
2) Quit
```

Then the `PS3` variable , in your system it is `#?` is displayed and waits for a user input. The `select` expects an input `1` or `2` when you press `1` the `name`(in syntax) ,ie  in your program `opt` will take the value `Hello`. It matches the first `if` which prints the output as `Hello world` This continues until an `EOF` is encountered.

In the program, the `exit` in `Quit` causes an exit when 2 is pressed.

Expected output:

```
1) Hello
2) Quit
#? 1   <= my input
Hello World
#? 2   <= my input
done
```

Comment: This doesn't explain what's actually wrong and is very hard to follow

Comment: @nu11pO1n73R thanks a lot I understood the program. Thanks for the help

Comment: @PeterR There is nothing wrong in the program. The problem was with the input provided, when the program was rum

Comment: Wait... They just pressed enter... Without entering anything?